# jquery: numeric input only, but also restrict number of characters

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery function to only allow numeric input.  It works fine, but client now wants to limit input to 8 numeric values.  Is there away, using the code below to also restrict the number of characters?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.numberinput').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        return !(e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 &&
                (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46);
    });
});​
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just add a `&& (this.value.length >= 8);` in your current return statement and it should work fine.

Comment: Could you not just put a `maxlength` attribute on the `<input>` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input.numberinput').bind('keypress', function (e) {
   if(this.value.length>= 8) 
          {
            alert('Maximum limit is 8'); return false;
          }
    return !(e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 &&
            (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46);
});
```

});​

Answer (score 0):

You can "[maxlength](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)" to restrict user

Answer (score -1):

Just check `this.value.length`, for example:

```
if(this.value.length >= 8) {
   alert('maximum of 8 characters.');
}
```